# how to set dynamic column name in web gridview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<div id="grid" class="ajaxGrid">
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(list, rowsPerPage: 8, canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid");
    }

    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        numericLinksCount: 10,
        firstText: "First",
        previousText: "Prev",
        nextText: "Next",
        lastText: "Last",
        columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column((string)(@<text>@item.Value</text>),format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.Text), "Search", "Home", new { id = item.Value }, new { @class = "clickable" }))))
</div>
```

When i execute the program the webgrid view is not displayed.. What is the error in the code?? can anyone post the answer for me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well

```
System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column
```

has the following constructor

```
Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)
```

So I don't see how your code can work, I mean you are passing wrong arguments to the constructor.

As a first argument you assign

`(string)(@<text>@item.Value</text>)`

But it should be string, so no lambda expression is possible.

That's the code, that works for me

```
@grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "head",
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        numericLinksCount: 10,
        firstText: "First",
        previousText: "Prev",
        nextText: "Next",
        lastText: "Last",
                columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column(header: "some column header", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.Text), "Index", "Home", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "clickable" }))))
```

So, just make sure you use Column constructor the right way.

Also good thread about topic http://tinyurl.com/9n39mgv

Comment: but i have done type conversion to string and all the constructor needed is the string using (string) (@<text>@item.Value</text>)..  now whats the error.. doesn't the type conversion work??

Comment: Please tell me what you are trying to achieve? It's a header name, usually - string constant like "Blah"

Comment: i have to send the header name dynamically to the controller when i click the header.. there are different tables in my database so i want to load the data from different tables to the webgrid at different time.. so i have to use the different header name for different tables.. so that i can know which table values are loaded in the gridview and sort data as by the header name..